# Can't display the checkbox and button in every rows of td

Tags: javascript, json

I can't  display the checkbox and button in every rows of td. Currently it appending in last rows td only. and how to append the checkbox and buttons in all rows in td.. Can anyone help me to do this?

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  table.appendChild(row);
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  row.appendChild(cell);
  cell.appendChild(checkbox);
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  row.appendChild(cell);
  cell.innerHTML = i;
  for (key in obj[i]) {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    row.appendChild(cell);
    cell.innerHTML = obj[i][key];
  }
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  row.appendChild(cell);
  cell.appendChild(btnEdit);
  cell.appendChild(btnSave);
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajaovi/LpfL6q2r/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what is happening is you are moving the input/buttons every time you append them to the cell because it is the same element.

To fix this you must create the checkbox and buttons in your for loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    var btnSave = document.createElement('button');
    btnSave.setAttribute ("id","saveBtn");
    btnSave.innerHTML = "Save";

    var btnEdit = document.createElement('input');
    btnEdit.type = "button";
    btnEdit.value = "Edit";

    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.id= "checkBox";

    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    table.appendChild(row);

    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    row.appendChild(cell);
    cell.appendChild(checkbox);

    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    row.appendChild(cell);

    cell.innerHTML = i;

    for (key in obj[i]) {
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        row.appendChild(cell);
        cell.innerHTML = obj[i][key];
    }

    var cell = document.createElement("td");

    row.appendChild(cell);
    cell.appendChild(btnEdit);
    cell.appendChild(btnSave);
}
```

Just as a side note, it is good practice that 'id' attributes be unique.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ronster37 is right, check the fiddle out: https://jsfiddle.net/LpfL6q2r/4/. I've added the index `i` to checkbox and button ids, to make them unique in your example.

Comment: and one help .. after selecting the checkbox and then I click the delete button . it's is possible to remove the selected row..

Comment: use even delegation for deleting and set unique ids while creating input elements